# Can I create parameterized views in oracle

Tags: oracle, view, parameterized

I have a query like this

```
SELECT ID,REF_ID,BATCHNO FROM reporttbl
where POSTING_DT >= '06/01/2020' and POSTING_DT <= '06/30/2020'
```

and I need it every month, so I would like to put it in a view, but as the date changes every month, it would be great to have a date parameter that I can pass to the view when calling it. Is there a way on how can i achieved this?
I'm new to oracle, appreciate every help. Thank youu.

Comment: Where are you calling it from?  e.g an application, from SQL Developer/Plus/Toad?

Comment: @TonyAndrews from oracle sql developer

Comment: Do you want to see the *current month* `trunc(sysdate,'MM')` or the *previous month* `add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),-1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to "parameterize" a view e.g. using Oracle contexts, but they aren't often useful and certainly not for your case.

If your query really just selects from one table with just the dates as predicates then a view doesn't add much value either.  You could create a SQL **script** (in a file e.g. myquery.sql) using bind variables:

```
SELECT ID,REF_ID,BATCHNO FROM reporttbl
where POSTING_DT >= to_date(:from_date) and POSTING_DT <= to_date(:to_date);
```

Then every month you can just open the file and run it, and it will prompt you for the 2 dates.  Or you can run as a script like this and it will also prompt you:

```
@myquery.sql
```

Or if you use substitution strings '&1.' and '&2.' instead:

```
SELECT ID,REF_ID,BATCHNO FROM reporttbl
where POSTING_DT >= to_date('&1.') and POSTING_DT <= to_date('&2.');
```

Then you can pass the dates in on the command line like this:

```
@myquery '06/01/2020' '06/30/2020'
```

(Because &1. means first parameter on command line, etc.)

Answer (score 9):

From 19.6 you can create parameterized views using [SQL macros](https://blog.sqlora.com/en/parameterized-views-in-oracle-no-problem-with-sql-macros/).

```
create or replace function get_month (
  tab dbms_tf.table_t, start_date date, end_date date
) return varchar2 sql_macro as
  retval int;
begin
  return 'select * from tab 
    where dt >= start_date and dt < end_date + 1';
end get_month;
/

create table t (
  c1 int, dt date
);

insert into t 
with rws as (
  select level c1, add_months ( date'2019-12-25', level ) dt 
  from   dual
  connect by level <= 10
)
  select * from rws;
  
select * from get_month ( 
  t, date'2020-06-01', date'2020-07-01' 
);

C1    DT                     
    6 25-JUN-2020 00:00:00    

select * from get_month ( 
  t, date'2020-08-01', date'2020-09-01' 
);

C1    DT                     
    8 25-AUG-2020 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the todays *learn each day a new Oracle feature*!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is using a function that retrieves the parameters from a table, thereby you don't need to manipulate any DDL. The idea here is

- Using a table to store the parameters, basically you need parameter value and a parameter description.
- Using a function to retrieve the value of that parameter when the input is the parameter name
- Using the function call inside the view.
- You can then manipulate the view automatically by modifying the values of the parameter table.

Table

```
create table my_param_table 
( param_description varchar2(100) , 
  param_value varchar2(100),
  enabled     varchar2(1)
) ;
```

Function

```
create or replace function f_retr_param  ( p_value in varchar2 )
return varchar2
is 
declare
v_value my_param_table.value_param%type;
begin
  select value into v_value from my_table_of_parameters 
  where upper(value_param) = upper(p_value) ;
  return v_value;
  exception when others then raise;
end;
/
```

View

```
create or replace force view my_view as 
SELECT ID,REF_ID,BATCHNO FROM reporttbl
where POSTING_DT >= f_retr_param ( p_value => 'p_start_date' );
and POSTING_DT <= f_retr_param ( p_value => 'p_end_date' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This query return the data for the *previous month*, i.e. the month befort the current month at the time of the query (= `sysdate`).

You use the `trunc` with `'MM'` to get the months first and the arithmetic with [`add_months`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions004.htm#SQLRF00603)

```
SELECT ID,REF_ID,BATCHNO FROM reporttbl
where POSTING_DT >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),-1) and POSTING_DT <  trunc(sysdate,'MM')
```