# Reg: Passing Parameters to SQL View

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

We have created 1 view it had logic for calculating business Hrs for Date_1 and Date_2, as we need to use the same logic with existing view and pass different date Date_3 and Date_4 instead of creating new view.

Was it possible can anyone suggest how to implement this.

Version we are using:  Oracle SQl developer Build 20.2.0.175

Regards,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create parameterized VIEW in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498364/create-parameterized-view-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Most probably not, @paulsm4, as this is **Oracle** (at least, PL/SQL tag suggests so). But this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62950106/can-i-create-parameterized-views-in-oracle), Oracle-related discussion, might help.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is **a development tool** and so its version is not particularly relevant to a question about SQL and/or PL/SQL functionality. It would be more helpful if you told us the version of the database you're connecting to (which is independent of the client you use to connect).

Comment: edit question with a [mcve]